# Reconnect to a BLE device after pulling the battery

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

I have a BLE device that I am writing an app to pair with.  I can discover and connect to the device with no problems.  But if I am connected and pull and reinsert the battery on the BLE device I get the `didDisconnectPeripheral` callback but I never get another `didConnectPeripheral` even though I'm still scanning.  I also tried calling `retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices` and `retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers` but neither of those return anything.

How can I reliably reconnect after cycling the power on my BLE device?

Comment: How does pulling the battery affect pairing mode on the peripheral?

Comment: It boots right back up and starts broadcasting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as the peripheral disconnects you can issue another connect - iOS will automatically reconnect to the device once it is visible again and call your `didConnectPeripheral:` delegate method

```
-(void) centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDisconnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral error:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Disconnected from peripheral");
    [central connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];
}
```

There is no need to rescan/re-discover the peripheral.

You may want a more comprehensive implementation that updates UI etc.

Here is some sample code that connects to a peripheral and displays the vendor information - 
https://github.com/paulw11/BTBackground

Comment: It's never calling my `didConnectPeripheral` again.  I notice you're using self.central instead of the `CBCentralManager` that is being passed into `didDisconnectPeripheral`.  Any reason for that?

Comment: No, it shouldn't matter.  In fact I changed the code when I copied it to my answer above.  What is your peripheral?  My sample project tested OK with a TI sensorTag and a LightBlue Bean

Comment: Ok, I was doing some additional stuff in my `didDisconnectPeripheral`.  Once I took it down to just what you have it works.  I need to figure out what was breaking it!  Thank you!

Comment: Wow, I was trying to solve this problem for quite some time, I added all kinds of methods in the didDisconnectPeripheral. This is beautiful and works well for me!